# Access API from backend from React directly on the server

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, axios

I am using Django as a backend and React for a frontend.
I am starting the react frontend using PM2 and accessing the Django backend via PM2. I also installed Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect querys to
* mydomain.toplevel/admin to the django admin
* mydomain.toplevel/ to the react frontend

The backend and frontend communicate via a REST api, using the DJANGO REST framework and Axios for React.

**My main question at the moment is: Is it possible to let the frontend and the backend communicate directly on the server, in order of not exposing the API to the internet?**

I guess not, because react, as a JS frontend, is executed on the client side - correct? Does this also hold if the React frontend is not served as static files (`npm run-server build`) but via PM2?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by only allowing your React application's domain. To do that;

1. Install `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. Add it to your installed apps

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'corsheaders',
    ...
 )
```

3. Add middleware classes to settings.py:

```
   MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
       'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       ...
  ]
```

4. Add your React app's domain to allow it inside settings.py

```
  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://your-react-apps-domain',
    'http://localhost:3000'
  )
```